# Селектор Jquery по родительским и дочерним атрибутам

Tags: jquery

Я новичок в jquery.

На страничке есть определенное количество элементов `td`. В каждом `td` есть несколько скрытых элементов `input`. Мне нужно селектнуть все `td` в которых есть атрибут `data-markid` и в которых есть `input` c `name = timetableId` и `value =` определенной переменной.

Пробовал подобную конструкцию, но она не работает, так как я предполагал

`$("[data-markid]").parents('[timetableId="' + timeTableSubjectId + '"]');`

Пример html разметки. Скажем есть некоторая переменная `var timeTableSubjectId = 34`. В таком случае мне нужно селектнуть первый элемент `td` из моего примера

```
<td class="" title="2 сентября 2019" data-markid="8">
                <input type="hidden" class="mark-type-hidden" name="MarkType" value="Работа на уроке">
                <input type="hidden" class="mark-title-hidden" name="MarkTitle" value="5">
                <input type="hidden" class="time-table-id" name="timetableId" value="34">
                <input type="hidden" name="MarkComment">
                <a onclick="marksBox.show(this)" class="#0e9bd0"> 5 </a>
</td>

<td class="" title="3 сентября 2019" data-markid="9">
                <input type="hidden" class="mark-type-hidden" name="MarkType" value="Работа на уроке">
                <input type="hidden" class="mark-title-hidden" name="MarkTitle" value="6">
                <input type="hidden" class="time-table-id" name="timetableId" value="201">
                <input type="hidden" name="MarkComment">
                <a onclick="marksBox.show(this)" class="#0e9bd0"> 6 </a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо использовать не parents, а parent (чтобы вернуть первого родителя, а не всех родителей вообще) + селектор по нескольким атрибутам (записываются слитно подряд, без всяких плюсов):

```js
$('[name="timetableId"][value="201"]').parent('td').css('background-color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="" title="2 сентября 2019" data-markid="8">
    <input type="hidden" class="mark-type-hidden" name="MarkType" value="Работа на уроке">
    <input type="hidden" class="mark-title-hidden" name="MarkTitle" value="5">
    <input type="hidden" class="time-table-id" name="timetableId" value="34">
    <input type="hidden" name="MarkComment">
    <a onclick="marksBox.show(this)" class="#0e9bd0"> 5 </a>
  </td>
  <td class="" title="3 сентября 2019" data-markid="9">
    <input type="hidden" class="mark-type-hidden" name="MarkType" value="Работа на уроке">
    <input type="hidden" class="mark-title-hidden" name="MarkTitle" value="6">
    <input type="hidden" class="time-table-id" name="timetableId" value="201">
    <input type="hidden" name="MarkComment">
    <a onclick="marksBox.show(this)" class="#0e9bd0"> 6 </a>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Пробовал подобную конструкцию, но она не работает, так как я предполагал
>
> $("[data-markid]").parents('[timetableId="' + timeTableSubjectId +
>   '"]');

Вам надо идти от обратного. Чтобы найти ячейку, надо смотреть только input с name & value и брать ближайшую к нему td

```js
let timeTableSubjectId = 34;
let td = $('[name="timetableId"][value="'+timeTableSubjectId+'"]').closest('td[data-markid]');
console.log(td);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="" title="2 сентября 2019" data-markid="8">
      <input type="hidden" class="mark-type-hidden" name="MarkType" value="Работа на уроке">
      <input type="hidden" class="mark-title-hidden" name="MarkTitle" value="5">
      <input type="hidden" class="time-table-id" name="timetableId" value="34">
      <input type="hidden" name="MarkComment">
      <a onclick="" class="#0e9bd0"> 5 </a>
    </td>
    <td class="" title="3 сентября 2019" data-markid="9">
       <input type="hidden" class="mark-type-hidden" name="MarkType" value="Работа на уроке">
       <input type="hidden" class="mark-title-hidden" name="MarkTitle" value="6">
       <input type="hidden" class="time-table-id" name="timetableId" value="201">
       <input type="hidden" name="MarkComment">
       <a onclick="" class="#0e9bd0"> 6 </a>
    </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно